# Increasing DJIFlightController update frequency

Tags: dji-sdk

Is it possible to get a `DJIFlightController` to call it's delegate method `didUpdateState` more than 10 times per second? It updates every 100ms according to [this](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/FlightController/DJIFlightController.html#djiflightcontroller_updatesystemstate_inline), but being able to adjust this would be very useful.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the reason why you want to updates the call frequency?

Comment: @dji-dev-Tim we are trying to obtain attitude data with finer granularity than this.

Comment: @Nick it's not supported in firmware, sorry about that